# DVD drive opening automatically

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I recently upgraded my Dell Inspiron 5558 to Ubuntu 18.04. Ever since the upgrade, the DVD drive keeps opening automatically at random times. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is still happening with 22.04.1. Anyone else suffering this should also tick "this bug also affects me" on Launchpad, here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1942299

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Ubuntu 18.04 have the `setcd` package available? If it is, install it and then run:

```
sudo setcd -s /dev/sr0
```

It should output something like this:

```
/dev/sr0:
  Auto close tray:     cleared
  Auto open tray:      cleared
  Use O_NONBLOCK flag: set
  Lock tray:           set
  Check CD type:       cleared
```

If "Auto open tray" says "set" instead, running `sudo setcd -o0 /dev/sr0` should fix your problem until the next reboot.

The root cause might be a tool in your desktop environment that can be used to mount removable disks. It polls the DVD drive every now and then. If the "Auto open tray" is set, the tray will open when the poll is done and the tool stops accessing the drive.

If disabling the "auto open" feature helps you, you might want to disable the "auto close" feature too, as it might try and close the drive just when you're about to place a disc on the tray. I had this problem with my system back in Debian 7 or so with KDE.

Ubuntu 18.04 has `systemd`, so probably the best way to make these settings persistent is to create a service file to run the necessary `setcd` command at boot time.

So, create a file in `/etc/systemd/system` with a descriptive name and a `.service` suffix. For example, let's call it `/etc/systemd/system/dvd-stop-open.service`. The contents of the file should be:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable DVD auto-open
Documentation=man:setcd(1)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setcd -o0 /dev/sr0
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once the service file is created, enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable dvd-stop-open.service
```

Test by starting the service and verifying that the `Active:` field in service status says `active (exited)`:

```
sudo systemctl start dvd-stop-open.service
systemctl status dvd-stop-open.service
```

---

Or alternatively, you can avoid changing systemd by simply inserting a '0' into /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoeject

Pick one:

Using rc.local:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoeject
```

Using /etc/crontab:

```
@reboot root    echo 0 > /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoeject
```

Or as a one-time, non-persistant across boots, command line use sudo:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/autoeject
```

This will take effect immediately. No sysctl or service file restart needed...

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have solved the issue. How do I make these settings stick on boot?

Comment: Answer updated with instructions for creating a simple `systemd` service file.

Comment: Tried both of these. Neither has any effect on Ubuntu 22.04.