# DVD-drive opens automatically on wakeup

Tags: dvd, manjaro

After updating my system to use Kernel **5.13.1-3-MANJARO**, my DVD drive opens up automatically after waking my rig up from suspend.

I have read [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1343049/dvd-drive-opening-automatically) already but the suggested fix won't help me.

Running `setcd` reveals:

```
/dev/sr0:
  Auto close tray:     set
  Auto open tray:      cleared
  Use O_NONBLOCK flag: set
  Lock tray:           cleared
  Check CD type:       cleared
```

And yet the drive opens up on every wakeup. Any ideas where else to look?

Answer (score -1):

The following UDEV fix worked for me without actually disabling the CD-ROM eject button function. The funny thing is that it does not work as it (apparently) should but it seems to work perfectly for this issue.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1725135#p1725135

Comment: put the content of the fix in the answer.